# Image added to Xamarin Forms not displaying

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a very simple Xamarin Forms app.  Essentially, it just displays an image of a form.  The image is part of the project (in the Assets folder).  However, I'm struggling to work out exactly what I need to do to get it to display the image.

Here's the Xaml:

```
<Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
   BackgroundColor="Aqua" Aspect="Fill" Source="../Assets/tmp.png"/>
```

I've tried various combinations of path (./Assets/tmp.png for example), I've even tried copying the image to the Assets folder in the UWP app that I'm trying to run, but I can't get the image to display.

Comment: Are you struggling just on UWP?

Comment: For UWP  <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/tmp.png" />  need to add ms-appx: scheme or <Image Source="Assets/tmp.png"  />

Comment: Have you looked at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos . And are the images turned in to embedded resources? and would it be a solution to put your images in the Resources folder instead?

Comment: Okay - my impression was that Xamarin would do the plumbing for the various platforms.  In fact, it actually translates the format to that which @Prasanth has suggested.

Comment: @MathiasKirkegaard I have looked at the docs - I came across the one that you've linked to initially and, as far as I can tell, am following it, and the image is set as an embedded resource.